# Get parrent category name

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, archives

I have 3 levels of categories:

```
Cat 1
- Cat 2
- Cat 3
-- Cat 4
```

I want to add Parent category name after page title. For example:

```
<h1>Cat 4</h1>
<p>From Cat3 in Cat 1</p>
```

But only for third level. Is it possible and what is the better way to do this correct?

I have fond a way to get Cat3, but I still bon't know, how to get previous category name and how to display the message for only third level.

```
$parent = get_queried_object()->parent;
if( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $parent, 'product_cat' ) ){
    echo '<span class="sub-cat">' . $term->name . '</span>';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How to accomplish it depends on your theme. You would first want to create a child theme, then copy whichever file applies - could be `category.php` or `archive.php` - and then add your code. Once you verify you're in the right file, build out the logic that checks the current category to see if it has a parent and grandparent, but not a great-grandparent, and if so outputs that paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a category description.
For example the Cat 4 will have the category description as : From Cat3 in Cat 1.

You add the category description when you edit the category inside of WP > Posts > Categories

Then to display the category description use this PHP code inside of your archive.php theme file:

```
<?php echo category_description(); ?>
```